# How to apply an `onclick` event to multiple radio button options in Scala Play?

Tags: html, forms, scala, playframework, google-analytics

I'm using the Play framework in Scala. 
 I have this radio button that lets you choose between two options from a form:

```
@helpers.inputRadioGroup(searchForm("options"), Seq("option1" -> "Option 1", "option2" -> "Option 2"))
```

I also have another form that doesn't use `helpers` and has `onclick` events that send data to Google Analytics depending on which option you choose:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="option1" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'searchForm', eventAction: 'options', eventLabel: 'option1'})" value="@searchForm("options")">Option 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option2" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'searchForm', eventAction: 'options', eventLabel: 'option2'})" value="@searchForm("options")">Option 2<br>
</form>
```

My question is how do I apply the second form's `onclick` events to the first example?

Comment: Couldn't you use Javascript/jQuery for this instead? Add a class name to the radios and have an onClick javascript function to handle the google analytics event.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Javascript/jQuery, do you have an example of how I could do that? @RobertUdah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the helper objects like `inputRadioGroup` has an `apply` method as documented here, for example (for play 2.3): https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputRadioGroup$

Here's the definition of `apply`:

```
def apply(
  field: Field,
  options: Seq[(String, String)],
  args: (Symbol, Any)*)(
  implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: Lang): 
  play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable
```

and then an example from the documentation

```
@inputRadioGroup(
  contactForm("gender"),
  options = Seq("M"->"Male","F"->"Female"),
  '_label -> "Gender",
  '_error -> contactForm("gender").error.map(_.withMessage("select gender")))
```

we see that tag attributes are provided as `varargs` in the form of a pair of `Symbol` and `Any`. So, we can rewrite your tag as follows:

```
@helpers.inputRadioGroup(
  searchForm("options"),
  Seq("option1" -> "Option 1", "option2" -> "Option 2"),
  'onclick -> "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'searchForm', eventAction: 'options', eventLabel: 'option1'})"
)
```